# Should I keep hiring for my current job, even after have giving notice myself?

Tags: interviewing

I'm a Tech Lead for a big company in Germany.

I worked here for the last three years, but recently resigned and I have two weeks left at this company.

The company is growing and wants to hire [X] developers. So I've been interviewing candidates even after giving my notice, and hired 3 new developers.

But during the interviews, people ask me questions that make me uncomfortable, like "What don't you like about your company?".

Because of this, I don't want to be part of interviews anymore, but my boss wants me to keep doing them because of our huge headcount.

Should I keep doing these interviews?

Edit: I feel uncomfortable answering these kind of questions because I don't want to bad mouth the company I'm leaving.

I am not happy working for this company anymore and a lot of the seniors and leaders of the company are also leaving. I can't really sell the company on interviews, but of course I do them anyway because it's my job.

So far I've been able to find answers that are only phrased in a very diplomatic way, but it feels like a I'm doing something wrong.

For example, the simple and honest answer I can think of is something like "I don't really like the direction the company has been taking", but that usually only makes people ask more questions.

Comment: " people ask me questions that make me uncomfortable" How did you handle those questions before you resigned?

Comment: Why does that question make you uncomfortable? And ask your boss how s/he wants that question answered. Both of you should be able to brainstorm a diplomatic answer that you are comfortable with.

Comment: Why do you thinks this has to do with ethics? This doesn't really sound like an ethical problem to me.

Comment: How is this a question about ethics, exactly?

Comment: @hasser, "What don't you like about your company?". This the first time I have ever heard any interviewees ask the interviewer such a question.  Did they ask that question because they knew that your are leaving your company ? If yes, who told them that you are leaving ? (You don't have to tell them that you are leaving during the interview.)

Comment: I don't tell them I'm leaving, but I'm interviewing people for senior and management positions and these kind of candidates are always prepared to get as much information about the company as they can.

Comment: "How did you handle those questions before you resigned?" I used to answer something honest, but was able to say at the end "but there are many good things, and the company is doing X to improve that". That's not the case anymore.

Comment: You're doing the right thing by asking this and being honest with yourself about it. Anyone hired on the basis of the interviewer's false enthusiasm would not last long either, so it would not benefit the company. One can make some evasive answers, to the effect of "the company is going through some significant changes, but will benefit from good new people, when it all settles down" or something like that. Someone who really needs the job would overlook it but at least have the benefit of some awareness, while someone with many options would go elsewhere - that's probably the best compromise.

Comment: You should. It is your workplace obligatory. You can ask your boss to get other tasks, but he can reject it.

Comment: Typically, boss requires you to do it in the lack of human resource. If others could do these interviews, he would ask them. Note: the last weeks are always hard, you could be in much bigger trouble, too. I would suggest to do it as if you would not be in the outgoing queue. Explain the boss this problem, and do what he says.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all. Really wonderful even after resigning your boss still put his faith on you for interview. Guess you are a trustworthy person (or your boss is short of experience interviewers)

I understand you may feel uncomfortable answering the question. Who wants to openly "bad mouth" their own or soon to be ex-employer. But you know what, there is nothing wrong with answering the question as long as you maintain professionalism at all times; keep it short and stick to the facts. No company is perfect and everyone knows it.It is in everyone interest to have honest interview for both the company and the interviewee.

Comment: +1 - things you consider a dealbreaker might not faze someone else.  If you think there’s a better path to product success say that diplomatically; if the problem is it’s hard for you to find work/life balance there say that.  Ideally you’re hiring people that do like the new company direction, just because it’s not for you doesn’t mean it’s wrong.  You may say “I know that” but tagging the question “ethics” makes me think maybe you have trouble distinguishing that.

Comment: +1: I would recommend an edit for "keep your mouth in check" to something more like, "maintain professionalism at all times". It's not just a mouth that can get someone in trouble.

Comment: @JoelEtherton thanks. I edited answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

If your boss is asking you to do the interviews, then you should do the interviews; it's your job to do what you're asked.

Absolutely sit down with your boss and let them know how you're feeling about these, though.  "Hey, when people ask me what I don't like about the company, it makes me feel uncomfortable, since I want to do right by the company while I'm here and not bad-mouth anyone.  What's a good way to answer that question?"

Then use whatever they tell you, so long as it's close enough to a truth that you feel okay with it.  Some of this depends on what you *actually* feel about the company; but if you really hate it there, and have lots of bad feelings, you're probably going to have to just keep those to yourself, or else you'd really burn bridges.